# Adding a custom rewrite rule for gallery/categories page

Tags: rewrite-rules

I've written a simple shortcode and using it on my gallery page. The URL for the page looks something like this:

```
http://mysite.dev/gallery/?view=category-name
```

but I want to be able to use

```
http://mysite.dev/gallery/category-name
```

When I use a URL like so, WP redirects to what seems the nearest match it can find. For example

```
http://mysite.dev/gallery/nature
```

redirects to

```
http://mysite/home/nature
```

I've tried implementing a rewrite rule:

```
function add_custom_rewrites()
{
    remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

    add_rewrite_rule('^gallery/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php/gallery/?category=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%category%', '(.+)');

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrites');
```

but the /gallery/category page always redirects to try and by some means find the nearest matching page.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I didn't need to remove the 'redirect_canonical' filter, and I only needed to change the 2nd parameter for add_rewrite_rule. The resulting function looks as follows:

```
function add_custom_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%category%', '(.+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^gallery/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=gallery&category=$matches[1]', 'top');

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrites');
```

Comment: you don't want to flush rewrite rules on every request, only do it on plugin/theme activation, or manually by visiting the permalinks settings page. read [`flush_rewrite_rules`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) for more info.